# Como unir registros de uma tabela distribuídos em vários arquivos .sqlite?

Tags: sql, sqlite, sqlite-studio

Tenho vários arquivos com extensão `.sqlite`, contendo cada 1 pelo menos uns 1000 registros totalizando assim, cerca de 4 mil registros. Vejam como são distribuídos:

- vihicles1.sqlite
- vihicles2.sqlite
- vihicles3.sqlite
- vihicles4.sqlite

Dentro de cada arquivo possui uma única tabela com o nome `tblVehicle` que contém as seguintes colunas:

- id (integer)
- make (text)
- model (text)
- year (int)

Estou usando o [SQLiteStudio](https://sqlitestudio.pl/index.rvt) para gerenciamento do banco de dados. É possível unir esses arquivos criando apenas 1 arquivo com todos os registros?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Anexe os arquivos na sessão, dê um `INSERT`  selecionando os dados da tabela em cada base de dados. O nome da base (sobrenome da tabela) vem antes da tabela.

```
ATTACH 'path/aqui/vihicles1.sqlite' as v1;         
ATTACH 'path/aqui/vihicles2.sqlite' as v2;
ATTACH 'path/aqui/vihicles3.sqlite' as v3;
ATTACH 'path/aqui/vihicles4.sqlite' as v4;

INSERT INTO tblVehicle SELECT * FROM v1.tblVehicle;
INSERT INTO tblVehicle SELECT * FROM v2.tblVehicle;
INSERT INTO tblVehicle SELECT * FROM v3.tblVehicle;
INSERT INTO tblVehicle SELECT * FROM v4.tblVehicle;

DETACH 'path/aqui/vihicles1.sqlite';
DETACH 'path/aqui/vihicles2.sqlite';
DETACH 'path/aqui/vihicles3.sqlite';
DETACH 'path/aqui/vihicles4.sqlite';
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/SQL/Insert/MergeDistribuided.sql).

Não ache que este caso seja muito necessário pelo volume baixo, mas algumas configurações podem ser úteis para melhorar a performance:

Alguns exemplos que podem ajudar:

```
PRAGMA synchronous = OFF
PRAGMA journal_mode = MEMORY
```

Isto não cria índices.

Você pode usar um dos arquivos para receber os demais, aí os índices já existem. Mas a importação pode ficar bem mais lenta. Não sei como está a otimização do SQLite, mas antigamente era mais rápido importar sem índice e depois criar o índice.

Seria bom testar algumas situações e ver como funciona melhor para você.

Comment: Demorou alguns segundos, por conter exatamente 18780 registros. Mas funcionou perfeitamente. o/